# Category with the same slug

Tags: permalinks

i'd like to do this:

```
www.website.ext/ciccio/pro
www.website.ext/mario/pro
www.website.ext/giuseppe/pro
```

Why can't i do that? I know.. the slug/child-category "pro" is the same but it is in the different parent categories. So, i don't know what I can do. :/

I tried but it doesn't work because every time wordpress change the category slug to: "child_category-parent_category".

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i've found this code, i think it is a good idea:

```
add_filter( 'post_link', 'remove_parent_cats_from_link', 10, 3 );
function remove_parent_cats_from_link( $permalink, $post, $leavename )
{
$cats = get_the_category( $post->ID );
if ( $cats ) {
// Make sure we use the same start cat as the permalink generator
usort( $cats, '_usort_terms_by_ID' ); // order by ID
$category = $cats[0]->slug;
if ( $parent = $cats[0]->parent ) {
// If there are parent categories, collect them and replace them in the link
$parentcats = get_category_parents( $parent, false, '/', true );
// str_replace() is not the best solution if you can have duplicates:
// myexamplesite.com/luxemburg/luxemburg/ will be stripped down to myexamplesite.com/
// But if you don't expect that, it should work
$permalink = str_replace( $parentcats, '', $permalink );
}
}
return $permalink;
}
```

but I have a trouble. It is not working with this structure:

**www.domain.com/taco/promotions-taco/2014/title-post/**

it become:

**www.domain.com/promotions-2014/title-post/** (why???)

But i'd like a structure like this:

**www.domain.com/promotions-taco/2014/title-post/**

is it possible?